# Performance Improvements with Processes or Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I've written a script that pulls data from my school's website and I'm having some trouble with execution time.

There are over 20 campuses, each with data for three semesters. The script looks up those school names, then the semesters available for each school, then the subjects/departments that are offering classes each semester. Then the script  searches for the classes per department and then I do things with that data.

I timed the execution of the script on just one campus, and it ran for over three minutes. When I ran it for all 24 campuses it took over an hour. I'm using the "requests" library, which runs each HTTP request in synchronously. I'm using the "requests" library, primarily because it handles sessions nicely.

I'm looking for ways to bring down the time the script takes to run, by making the various requests for each semester run in parallel. I suspect that if I run three semesters asynchronously, then each school should take a minute, instead of three. Then, I can run all schools in parallel and achieve the same minute for all of the data. A minute is a lot less than an hour and a quarter!

1. Am I wrong in my guess that multithreading/processing will bring down the execution time so drastically? What Python libraries should I be using for threads or processes?
2. Once I've got each school being processed on a  thread, how do I consolidate the data from all the schools into one place? I know that it's considered poor practice for threads to alter global state, but what's the alternative here?

Comment: Don't really know Python, but what you describe is exactly why threads were invented in the first place:  Even on a uni-processor machine, threads are a way of organizing a program that must wait for two or more things at the same time (e.g., waiting for two or more HTTP replies on different sockets).

Comment: Beware, Python threads can't make use of multiple cores. You may still see a performance increase from them, but if your goal is running multiple things simultaneously, look at multiprocessing, which can utilize multiple cores. Alternatively, other Python implementations, such as Jython, can run multiple threads on multiple cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are not wrong. Use `threading` library for threads. For processes you can use `multiprocessing` or `os.fork` or `subprocess` depending on how exactly you want to use them.

2) Who says that altering global state is a poor practice? That always depends on the context. Obviously you have to share a data structure between threads somehow. You don't have to use global variables for that though. For example:

```
from threading import Thread

def my_task(id, holder, some_other_args):
    # do something
    holder[id] = my_result

def main():
    total_data = {}
    threads = []
    for i in range(100):
        t = Thread(target=my_task, args=(i, total_data, ...))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    print total_data  # <-- you have all results here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you want multiprocessing over multithreading. Threads don't do well in Python beacause of the GIL.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a global var ? Same code as freakish but without a global var passed to the threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        super().__init__(target=target, name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        self.output = None
    def run(self):
        self.output = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)


def my_task(i):
    # do something
    return 'response ' + str(i)

def main():
    total_data = list()
    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        t = MyThread(target=my_task, args=[i,])
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        total_data.append(t.output)

    print(total_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output is :

```
Jean@MyDesktop:~$ ./test_threads.py 
['response 0', 'response 1', 'response 2', 'response 3', 'response 4']
```

@yorodm: in this case I think multithreading should be enough, unless heavy processing is done localy on the data.

Comment: Nice. I'm using python 2. Also, I do intend to do heavy processing on the data once I've got it in hand.